# Phalcon invalid document error

Tags: phalcon

I have a Phalcon\Mvc\Collection model called User. When I try to get a user by their email like this

```
User::findFirst(array("conditions" => array("email" => $email)));
```

I get two different results. If the variable $email contains an email present in the database, I get a result as expected. However, if the variable $email does NOT contain an email that is present in the database, I get an "Invalid document" message.

Phalcon version 0.8.0. It also does seem to hold true with version 0.7.0.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: This seems to be a bug can you report the bug here https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues

Comment: Thank you. The bug has been posted.